# how to get Spring LDAP user details on jsp without using scriplets

Tags: spring, jsp, ldap, jstl

I have used LDAP authentication using spring and it is working.

Now I want to show the details of authenticated user on jsp page without using scriplets. User details should be picked from http session. But I am not getting the right way to proceed further.

If anyone knows the solution then please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Spring taglib

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

You can then access the user principal (containing DN, groups, etc) with

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.<whatever>" />
```